# How to get programmatically limit message storage which it is in Message Queueing Properties?

Tags: c#, com, msmq

How  to get programmatically limit message storage which it is in Message Queueing Properties?
It defines size of all queues - global quota.
I am creating a simple monitor program which monitoring sizes of queues. I use MSMQ COM in C#, and i can't find that property. I can only find out how many bytes are in all queues and how many bytes is in particular queue. Default size (quota ) of queue is set on -1 which means  infinity.

[image]

Comment: ok i found that in registry : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ

Comment: so how did you determine how many bytes are in all queues and particular queue